# SQL Server CASE in WHERE clause with daterange

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a query with optional date range parameters that I am trying to work out with a case but struggling.

- If both dates are NULL, return everything including NULL date rows
- If both have values, return only those within range
- If from_date has value, and to_date null, return everything > from_date
- If from_date is null, and to_date has value, return everything < to_date

so basically something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CASE WHEN (@FROM_DATE IS NOT NULL and @TO_DATE IS NOT NULL) THEN
   DATE BETWEEN ISNULL(@FROM_DATE,1/1/1900) and ISNULL(@TO_DATE,1/1/2999)
ELSE
   DATE = DATE ?
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have decided that dates in 1900 and 2999 won't occur in the data legitimately so you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  (@FROM_DATE IS NULL AND @TO_DATE IS NULL )
        OR (DATE BETWEEN ISNULL(@FROM_DATE, '19000101') 
           AND ISNULL(@TO_DATE, '29990101')) 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Can I ask why the Option (RECOMPILE) ?

Comment: THANKS, this seems to work!  Those dates will most likely be out of the scope, I just didn't really know of any other way to do it.  If there is anything more efficient I'd certainly be open to suggestions

Comment: @Jay - Well the most efficient and robust way that doesn't require use of sentinel values or recompile would be a separate query for all the four different cases. But you may prefer this for maintainability particularly if compile time is trivial and it is not frequently executed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll just use this for now.  Seems to do the trick.  I just need to check performance.  Thanks again!!